# Re-activate a suspended G Suite subscription at the end of its annual commitment interval

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-reseller-api

We have a system that manages our G Suite Reseller via the API.

Given a G Suite subscription that has been suspended because it has already passed its annual commitment period (and its renewal setting is set to "CANCEL" i.e. be suspended after its commitment period), will the "Activate" request be enough to immediately re-activate the subscription with the same plan details that it had before (i.e. same plan and renewal settings)?

I have checked this article and it only mentions briefly that to activate a suspended account, the **activate** code simply has to be called:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/subscriptions/changeRenewalSettings#renewalType

Could anyone clarify or verify this? I am unable to test it since our G Suite sandbox environment does not have any subscriptions that have already exceeded its commitment period (and I am unable to create one with that setup either).

Answer (score 0):

It was clearly stated in the [G Suite Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4377734?hl=en) to "**`Avoid suspension`**".

However, if it happen, you can follow the steps on [how to renew an expired domain registration](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6152355).

But you have to consider this:

> Note: We can't guarantee that you can renew an expired domain
>   purchased through Google. It depends on whether the domain is still
>   available from your domain host. In any case, try to renew the domain
>   right away. The longer you wait, the less likely you'll be able to
>   renew. As a general rule, you should renew within 19 days of the
>   official renewal date to increase the chances that you can renew
>   successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first  [changeplan](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/subscriptions/changePlan) with `customerId`/`domain` and `subscriptionId` 
Then call [activate](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/subscriptions/activate).

NOTE:

1. calling activate on subscriptions which are suspended after trail was completed will result in failure.But if the plan is set you can call activate.
2. Pay attention to `suspensionReasons` in API response.